# Multiple ProducesResponseType for same status code 200OK

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I am using swagger ui and I have action like this in my controller:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(PublicDto), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(PrivateDto), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUser(string id)
{
    try
    {

        ...

        if (...) 
        {
            var dto = _mapper.Map<PrivateDto>(user);
            return Ok(dto);
        }
        else
        {
            var dto = _mapper.Map<PublicDto>(user);
            return Ok(dto);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.LogError(ex, "Error inside action");
        return StatusCode(500, "Internal server error");
    }
}
```

The problem is that on my swagger UI page I can see only one of them in Responses area, and got scheme for only one. Is there a way to have more than one objects for response for one status code?

Comment: You can refer to the source code of [ProducesResponseTypeAttribute](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ProducesResponseTypeAttribute.cs) ,it can only put one type to `public ProducesResponseTypeAttribute(Type type, int statusCode)`.

Comment: @YiyiYou my question wasn`t about sending 2 types in one attribute. I need to get 2 separate attributes with same status code, the problem is that in my swagger ui I can see only one per status code in Responses

Comment: Did you find any solution to this?

Comment: @MattiasNordqvist No, I did not

Comment: It's considered as bad api design. The "better" solution is to have two endpoints.

Comment: @SkorunkaFrantišek Why is it considered bad api design? 
In my api, I can return a Result-object which either is a success or a fail. If it is a success, it has a value, if it is a fail, it has at least one error message. I can certainly not have 2 different endpoints for successful and failing results.

Comment: It's not good idea, because a client should parse the response to understand the concrete type and select correct deserializer. You could use the parent class of the both responses, additional headers or different status codes to help client to solve the question, but nevertheless it seems like bad API design and doesn't correspond to RESTful.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a bug it’s a limitation of the open api specification, which SB is built on. Specifically you can only have one response object per response code. See https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.1.0#responses-object

Comment: Now there is OneOf option available in specification would should support this.

Answer (score 0):

I use https://github.com/mcintyre321/OneOf for this purpose.

ClientFilePatchResult.cs (response model)

```cs
[GenerateOneOf]
public partial class ClientFilePatchResult
    : OneOfBase<
        ClientUpdateResult,
        DivisionUpdateResult,
        LinkedPartyUpdateResult,
        ContactUpdateResult,
        None>
{
}
```

ClientFileController.cs

```cs
    [HttpPatch]
    [Route("{id}")]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(ClientFilePatchResult), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateField([FromRoute] int id, [FromBody] ClientFilePatchVm model)
    {
        ...
        var result = await _jobService.PatchAsync(id, sm);
        return result.Value is None ? Ok() : Ok(result.Value);
    }
```

OneOfOperationFilter.cs (see https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#operation-filters)

```cs
public class OneOfOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    private static IReadOnlyList<Type> GetGenericParameterTypes(Type type)
    {
        if (type.IsGenericType && type.IsAssignableTo(typeof(IOneOf)))
        {
            return type.GetGenericArguments().ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Type {type.FullName} is not assignable to {typeof(IOneOf)}");
        }
    }

    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        var oneOfResponseAttributes = context.MethodInfo
            .GetCustomAttributes()
            .OfType<ProducesResponseTypeAttribute>()
            .ToList()
            .AsReadOnly();

        if (!oneOfResponseAttributes.Any())
            return;

        // process all ProducesResponseType attributes
        foreach (var oneOfResponseAttribute in oneOfResponseAttributes)
        {
            var statusCode = oneOfResponseAttribute.StatusCode;
            var oneOfResponseType = oneOfResponseAttribute.Type;

            // skip if current type is not IOneOf
            if (!oneOfResponseType.IsAssignableTo(typeof(IOneOf)))
                continue;

            // find parent class of type OneOf<T1, ...> or OneOfBase<T1, ...>
            while (oneOfResponseType is { IsGenericType: false })
            {
                oneOfResponseType = oneOfResponseType.BaseType;
            }

            // skip if unable to find appropriate parent class
            if (oneOfResponseType == null)
                continue;

            var allOneOfTypes = GetGenericParameterTypes(oneOfResponseType);

            var oneOfSchemas = new List<OpenApiSchema>();

            foreach (var oneOfType in allOneOfTypes)
            {
                var oneOfTypeSchema = context.SchemaGenerator.GenerateSchema(oneOfType, context.SchemaRepository);
                if (oneOfTypeSchema != null)
                {
                    oneOfSchemas.Add(oneOfTypeSchema);
                }
            }

            if (oneOfSchemas.Any())
            {
                var operationResponse = operation.Responses[statusCode.ToStringInvariant()];
                operationResponse.Content.Clear();
                operationResponse.Content["application/json"] = new OpenApiMediaType
                {
                    Schema = new OpenApiSchema
                    {
                        Type = "object",
                        OneOf = oneOfSchemas,
                    },
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As a result, I can see an appropriate schema in my swagger UI:

```json
          "200": {
            "description": "Success",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "object",
                  "oneOf": [
                    {
                      "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ClientUpdateResult"
                    },
                    {
                      "$ref": "#/components/schemas/DivisionUpdateResult"
                    },
                    {
                      "$ref": "#/components/schemas/LinkedPartyUpdateResult"
                    },
                    {
                      "$ref": "#/components/schemas/ContactUpdateResult"
                    },
                    {
                      "$ref": "#/components/schemas/None"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
```

[image]